# How to add 2 layers in qgis and display them at the same time

Tags: qgis, python

I added 2 layers in qgis using python but only one layer is shown on canvas. After clicking (anywhere on the canvas) both layers are displayed.

```
layer =  QgsVectorLayer("Point?field=gid:integer","items","memory")

maplayer=QgsVectorLayer("IND_adm1.shp","IND_adm1.shp","ogr")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([maplayer,layer])
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(X,Y)) )
feature.setAttributes(values)
layer.startEditing()
layer.addFeature(feature, True)
layer.commitChanges()
layers=[]
layers.append(maplayer)
layers.append(layer)
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layers[0])])
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layers[1])])
canvas.refresh()
canvas.show()
```

when it run on qgis it will shows only second layer and when i click on canvas it shows both layer
how could I avoided this one click and both layer should be displayed directly using python.

Comment: Can you please add some minimal code example that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a vector layer and you use the python console of qgis you can use:

```
vlayer1 = QgsVectorLayer('poly1.shp','l1', 'ogr')
vlayer2 = QgsVectorLayer('poly2.shp','l2', 'ogr')

#You can add a list of vector layers at the same time
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vlayer1, vlayer2])

#Probably you also need the refresh function to reload your map canvas
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

At least in qgis 2.6 python console it is sufficient to execute the addMapLayers function without to refresh the canvas.

But like Matthias Kuhn said, a bit of code would be helpful.

Comment: i have add one layer from database and one from file path for me this solution is not working. database vector lyaer should be overlay on other one.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to add **`layer.updateExtents()`** just after `layer.commitChanges()`. It is necessary if features are added or deleted to the layer as mentioned in the [QGIS API Documentation!](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a151270aa47792b0f9eb72b96e03540c7)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It still require one click then only it shows both layer properly

Comment: its not working plz tell me any other solution